# Copying offline forum's webpages from Google cache to new forum

Tags: caching, web, forum, recover

Please first consider the following scenario:
I had a public forum online. accidentally all its database is lost and I am not able to get it anywhere. Now I have the only solution to get it from cached resources on web.

I want to know that is there a way to copy webpages of my forum from Google cache and directly put them on my other newly created forum? I must be possible but I don't know how. Can anyone help me?

The other question is if I managed to recover all the pages using [Warrick](http://code.google.com/p/warrick/) on my hard disk, how is it possible to create DB from those pages?

Please help me out I shall be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to recreate a database from Googles cached version of your site without manually entering every single user (and all of their profile information) and rewriting every single post from scratch.